# Proving the following is surjective (not sure about my solution)

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Question: Let *X* = *Map* (N, R) (X is set of functions from Natural numbers to real numbers).  The function *c*: *X* -> *X* is defined by (*c*(*f*))(*x*) = *f*(*x^2*).  Prove that *c* is a surjection.

Proof:

Consider *g* ∈ *X*.  Then g is a function from N to R.  We have to show that there exists *f* ∈ *X* such that *c*(*f*) = *g* i.e. *f(x^2)= g(x)* for every natural number *x*.

Let us define *f* as follows.  *f*: N -> R where *f*(0) = *g*(0) and *f*(1) = *g*(1).

So, *f*(r)={*g*($\sqrt{r}$); if *r* is a perfect square

{ 1; otherwise

Thus *f* is a pre-image of *g* under *c*.